# Char Pointer to Pointer Array - get size of first pointer array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have two char pointer arrays:

```
char* mainMenu[] = {"Start", "Mode"};
char* subMenu[] = {"Mode1", "Mode2", "Mode3"};
```

I put both arrays in an array containing pointer to pointer:
`char **menus[] = {mainMenu, subMenu};`

Now I'd like to get the size of the `subMenu` array by using `menus`.

With `subMenu` it works:

```
int num = sizeof(subMenu)/sizeof(subMenu[0]);  // num = 3
```

But I'd like to do this with `menus`, i tried:

```
int num2 = sizeof(*(menus[1]))/sizeof(*(menus[1]))[0];  // num2 = 2
```

What do i have to do with menus to get `3` as a result?

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof menus / sizeof menus[0]);` outputs `2`, which is the same way you did it before.

Comment: yes i know, but my question is, how can i get 3 as a result using `sizeof` and `menus`.
(don't want to get the result by using `subMenu`)

Comment: You *cannot* find the length of an array by dereferencing a pointer. It is impossible to know how many valid elements there are. The lengths will have to part of the containing structure too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking about de-reference. Something like
> `sizeof(*(menus[1]))/sizeof(*(menus[1])[0])`. Why doesn't it work ?

It doesn't work because `menus`is not an array of arrays but an array of pointers. The `submenu` identifier used to initialize `menus` is a taken as a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

For any array in C, this holds:

```
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])
```

Doesn't matter if it's an array of `char*`, `char**` or some other type. With your arrays:

```
char* mainMenu[] = {"Start", "Mode"};
char* subMenu[] = {"Mode1", "Mode2", "Mode3"};
char **menus[] = {mainMenu, subMenu};
printf("mainMenu %zu\n", SIZE_OF_ARRAY(mainMenu));
printf("subMenu %zu\n", SIZE_OF_ARRAY(subMenu));
printf("menus %zu\n", SIZE_OF_ARRAY(menus));
```

Comment: yes i know, but my question is, how can i get 3 as a result using `sizeof` and `menus`. (don't want to get the result by using `subMenu`)

Comment: @Dede_ You can't get the result 3 because it contains 2 items. If you want to de-reference it to get the size of its members you have to do something less "raw", for example by creating arrays of structs that store both the string and its size.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about de-reference. Something like `sizeof(*(menus[1]))/sizeof(*(menus[1])[0])`. Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: @Dede_ Because the fact that `mainMenu` etc are arrays is lost when set a `char**` to point at them. A `char**` can only be used to point at pointers, it is not an array and knows nothing of arrays. But `sizeof` needs an array to work.

Comment: @Dede_ See my first comment.